# jQuery hiding text only in <h2> block not background

Tags: jquery, text, show-hide

I have an `<h2>` text title block with a set background color and text content. I want to hide the text content and not the background color. When I use hide() on the `<h2>` it hides the whole block with everything. I need the block with the color and then I want the text to appear later.

I was thinking of wrapping it in a div and using the background color of the div but it will result in extra code.

Is it possible to control just text content only within the the `<h2>` and not the entire box?

Answer (score 3):

You could replace the text of the `h1` with `&nbsp;`. That would preserve the vertical space consumed by the element, but with no text showing. (Don't replace its text with a blank string, the element would effectively disappear.)

Expressed as a jQuery plug-in (although that may be a bit overkill :-) ):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hideText = function() {
        this.html(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.attr('data-oldtext', $this.html());
            return '&nbsp;';
        });
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.showText = function() {
        this.html(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            return $this.attr('data-oldtext') || $this.html();
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/evafa5)

That said, I'd step back a moment and consider whether this really is the right thing to do. It may well be, but it seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 2):

What about making the text the same colour as the background?

Comment: clever idea! really out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. You cannot 'hide' just the text.

That being said you can simulate it being hidden in a couple of ways:

**1)** You can remove the text, storing it locally then reset it on unhide.

```
var txt;
function hide() {
  txt = $('h2').text();
  $('h2').text('');
}
function show() {
  $('h2').text(txt);
}
```

However, this will make you have to have a static width/height on the`<h2>`element or it will change size when you change the text.

**2)** Making the text color match the background color also could simulate 'hiding' the text.

**3)** Or probably the best option, just wrap it in a div with a background color, and call it a day.

Answer (score 1):

Why not wrap the text inside the header like this then hide the inner element:

```
<h2><span>Your text here</span>&nbsp;</h2>
```

then in jQuery, use the following selector:

```
$('h2 > span');
```

Edit: @T.J. Crowder's suggestion is indeed a good one, you can always put an `&nbsp;` after your wrapped text to make the `<h2>` always keep its height.

Answer (score 0):

You could set `text-indent` to `-9999px` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

rather than using hide(), you can just change the h2 text color to be the same as the background color, that would create a hide effect:

```
$('h2').css('color','your-background-color');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$('h2').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3
}).wrap('<b />');
```

This will wrap the text with a `<b>` tag.
in your css set the `<b>` tag to `display:none;`. This will hide the text and not the `h2` tag.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/BE8N9/1/